# Is this a typo on LU Factorization page of Matlab or am I missing something?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know,

> A square matrix is called lower triangular if all the entries above
>   the main diagonal are zero.

I was looking at LU factorization of a matrix and there was an online tool that allows to use MATLAB LU function.

How is this a valid LU factorization when $L$ is not even a lower triangular matrix?
[image]

I did it by hand and I get $$L=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\-3/10&1&0\\1/2&-25&1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$U=\begin{pmatrix}10&-7&0\\0&-1/10&6\\0&0&155\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab has stated clearly in its [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lu.html) that what it does is a PLU factorisation, not an LU factorisation:

> [L,U] = lu(A) factorizes the full or sparse matrix A into an upper triangular matrix U and a permuted lower triangular matrix L such that A = L*U.
>
> [L,U,P] = lu(A) also returns a permutation matrix P such that A = P'*L*U. With this syntax, L is unit lower triangular and U is upper triangular.

A PLU factorisation is more desirable because LU factorisation may fail in practice.